# How does $Y_n$ approach $\theta$ in probability here?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, statistical-inference

From *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger:

> $\text{(Delta Method)}$ Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables that
>   satisfies $\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \theta) \rightarrow n(0,\sigma^2)$ in
>   distribution.  For a given function $g$ and a specific value of
>    $\theta$, suppose that $g'(\theta)$ exists and is not $0$.  Then
>    $\sqrt{n}[g(Y_n) - g(\theta)] \rightarrow n(0, \sigma^2[g'(\theta)])$
>   in distribution.
>
> The taylor expansion of $g(Y_n)$ around $Y_n = \theta$ is $$g(Y_n) = g(\theta) + g'(\theta)(Y_n-\theta) + \text{ Remainder, }$$
>   where the remainder $\rightarrow 0$ as $Y_n \rightarrow \theta$.
>
> **Since $Y_n \rightarrow \theta$ in probability**, it follows that the remainder $\rightarrow 0 $ in probability.

Why does $Y_n \rightarrow \theta$ in probability?  This isn't assumed in the statement of the theorem, so why is this true?

Comment: We know $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)\to N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution,  This implies $Y_n\to\theta$ in probability using a simple Borel-Cantelli estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $Z_n=\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\theta)$. We know that $Z_n \to Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution. Also $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. 
Then by Slutsky's theorem
$Y_n-\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Z_n \to 0\cdot Z=0$ in distribution and hence in probability.

Answer (score 0):

$P(|\sqrt n (Y_n-\theta)| >t) -2(1-\Phi (t))$ $\to 0$ uniformly in $t$ because convergence of distribution functions is uniform when the limiting distribution is continuous. So $P(|\sqrt n (Y_n-\theta)| >\sqrt n \epsilon) -2(1-\Phi (\sqrt n \epsilon))$ $\to 0$. Since $1-\Phi (\sqrt n \epsilon) \to 0$ we are done.